# Как доделать функцию чтобы он искал нужный результат не во всём документе а именно в переменной data которую он получил

Tags: ajax, for

Он выгружает информацию но ставит её не правильно (хаотично) Как доделать функцию чтобы он искал нужный результат не во всём документе а именно в переменной data которую он получил

...................................................................................

Пример: `var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event')`

```
function post_content(){
    var post_id = document.getElementsByClassName("post_ids"),
    j = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < post_id.length; i++){ 
        j = post_id[i].innerText.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
        if(j.length>0){     
            getAjaxPost(j);
        }else{
            j = "";
        }
    }
}

function getAjaxPost(id) {
    var tag_id = document.getElementById(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "cart/post_content.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({post_set:"set",post_id : id}),
        success: function(data){
            tag_id.innerHTML = data;
            var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event'),
            d = document.getElementById('d');
            d.innerHTML =  articles[articles.length-1].outerHTML.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: сузить поиск можно как минимум заменив `document`, на `tag_id` в вызове

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло очень.

Comment: Извените чайника за глупые вопросы...